# How to use fill aesthetic in geom_sf only for filtered values while ‘excluded’ and ‘NA’ values both presented on map with other colours

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, r-sf, geom-sf

I want to use `Spectral` palette from `RColorBrewer` only for AREA greater than 0.1, but I also wanted to show AREA less than 0.1 with let’s say dark grey or even better with hatched. In addition to this, I want to render `NA` as light grey. So basically, no values left behind in the map; they only get different colors. I tried with two below way but none of them works the way I want. Would appreciate any help on this.

```
library(ggnewscale)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), 
                  quiet = TRUE)

# add some NAs
nc$AREA[c(1,2,3)] <- NA

# first try
ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA > 0.1)) +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "Spectral"),
                       na.value = "grey90")
# second try
remove_col <- "AREA"
remove_val <- 0.1

nc %>%
  filter(.data[[remove_col]] < remove_val) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA)) +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = .data[[remove_col]]), color = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "Spectral"),
                       na.value = "grey90")
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If leaving `NA` and `< .1` from legend is acceptable, we can skip `ggnewscale`. First lets set limits for `scale_fill_gradientn()` to `c(.1, NA)` , everything outside the limits is filled with `na.value`. Then add another layer, only polygons with missing `AREA` values and constant fill:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), 
                  quiet = TRUE)

# add some NAs
nc$AREA[c(1,2,3)] <- NA

ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA))  +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "Spectral"),
                       limits = c(.1, NA),
                       na.value = "darkgrey") +
  geom_sf(data = ~ filter(.x, is.na(AREA)), fill = "lightgrey")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks this is great. Is there a way to add light and dark grey colors as sepreate legends?

Comment: Also, (this point was not in my question at first but I wonder what would be the answer): is there a way to use `limit` in `scale_fill_gradientn` based on another variable? For instance limits the `AREA` varibale based on values of variable `x`